# How to reverse the y-axis in a Google Sheets graph?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have data that represents the depth of an open mine in a transversal view.

Currently, it looks like this:

[image: The graph as it is now]

But since it represents the depth of a mine, I'd rather have it "flipped". So the y-axis, instead of going from 0 to 400, would need to go from 400 to 0.

And it would end up looking like this:

[image: The graph as I want it]

For now I did *-1 on all Y values to get the look of the second image, but that makes it go from -400 to 0, not exactly what I want.

I feel like this is probably a matter a checking a checkbox...

Comment: I'm not familiar with Google Sheets. Can you manipulate the values that are shown on the axis? Then having negative values *and* multiplying axis values with -1 (or using abs() function) would give you the desired result.

Answer (score 6):

This may not be a direct help since i think you also need an offset, not just a reversal, but for people who just need to reverse the whole axis, this may work

It's a ridiculous workaround.

- Make a new column, make it equal to zero minus your data column for the vertical axis
- Replace the data column address in the chart with this new column
- Select the column
- Click format>number>more formats>custom number format
- Change the number format to `-#;#` this will label your positives as negatives, and negatives as positives

Since you have already got the negative of your figures, the chart draws them upside down.

Since the default number format of the data for the vertical axis is "from data", sheets will obligingly label your chart in the correct order.

Change the format to match the format you want, just remember to add a `-` to the format before the semicolon and delete the `-` from the format after the semicolon.

Answer (score 3):

I think I found the answer to this.
1. Select Chart Editor
2. Select Vertical axis
Should be an option there for Reverse axis order

Comment: There isn't an option for the vertical axis. Only the horizontal axis

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. All you need to do is to change how negative numbers are displayed.

1. Format your data range by clicking the "123" format number button
2. Choose "More formats"
3. Create a format where the negative looks the same as a positive - for example #,##0;#,##0

Answer (score -3):

Multiply your values by -1 to switch from positive to negative and vice versa

Comment: That's already in the question